# Access Denied error accessing BitLocker encrypted fixed drive

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, permissions, encryption

BitLocker was turned on on my previous Windows 7. It was working properly until I had to change my Windows 7 and reinstall it on another drive, this time SSD instead of HDD. After installing Windows 7, I got "Access Denied" error message when i went to unlock the drive. The password was correct and the drive could unlock, but access was denied. I tried the built-in Administrator account and found that it had not this problem. It could access the contents of the drive and unlock. This was while my account was also an administrator of the new Windows. So, I decided to rename login name of the built-in Administrator account to my own and use it instead of my own account. This seemed that resolved the problem. Then, I decided to upgrade this Windows to 10. Now, after upgrading, I can't access the drive with the built-in Administrator account too!

### Notes:

1. In my previous Windows which I could see the contents of the drive, I was seeing a tiny lock icon on the root folders (the folders which were located on the root of the drive), while this didn't appear on their sub-folders. What is that?
2. Now and before upgrading, I might and may access the contents of the drive by using Total Commander. This seems the only way. It can't access and then brings up a dialog and asks for using administrative rights. If I click the button, it may show the contents! why? I'm the administrator already!
3. Issues like permissions in security or ownership seem not to be applicable, since they're set to both System and Administrators which I think that they're not Windows dependent and use the same GUID around all Windows.

Answer (score 1):

In properties of the drive, I chose Security tab and changed owner to "Everyone". It seems that BitLocker didn't cause the problem. It's weird, because I'm the admin, and Administrators was added to have Full Control access to objects which were not accessible.